# Using AND with OR operator in WHERE clause

Tags: mysql

In my mysql query, there is a bunch of AND conditions with one OR statement. But I need to fix my code such that either of my two given dates are between t2.start_id and t2.end_id, and still be ANDed to the other AND statements.

Right now, my OR statement executes and doesn't check with the other AND statements

```
SELECT * 
FROM med_files t1 Inner Join med_users t2 ON t1.med_id = t2.id 
WHERE t1.med_id in  (54810,54812,54813,54811)  AND t2.user_id <> 6 AND  
              '2014-07-16 00:00:00' between t2.start_id AND  t2.end_id OR 
              '2014-07-17 09:54:00' between t2.start_id AND  t2.end_id'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delineate the boundaries between each of the 2 checks with parentheses like so:

```
AND t2.user_id <> 6 
AND --Either of the two should be true
(
 ('2014-07-16 00:00:00' between t2.start_id AND  t2.end_id) 
 OR   
 ('2014-07-17 09:54:00' between t2.start_id AND  t2.end_id)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to use **parentheses** to seperate `AND` & `OR`

Try this

```
SELECT * 
FROM med_files t1 INNER JOIN med_users t2 ON t1.med_id = t2.id 
WHERE t1.med_id IN (54810,54812,54813,54811)  AND t2.user_id <> 6 AND  
              (('2014-07-16 00:00:00' between t2.start_id AND  t2.end_id) OR 
               ('2014-07-17 09:54:00' between t2.start_id AND  t2.end_id))
```

Answer (score 0):

Parentheses will do the job, they control the priority of your AND's and OR's, and group them together:

```
where 
  t1.med_id in (54810,54812,54813,54811)  
  AND t2.user_id <> 6 
  AND  ('2014-07-16 00:00:00' between t2.start_id AND  t2.end_id 
  OR '2014-07-17 09:54:00' between t2.start_id AND  t2.end_id')
```